# Doxygen 1.8.13 ignores parameters with default values (C++)

Tags: c++, doxygen

We are currently making our comments Doxygen-compatible, but have stumbled upon an issue with default parameters.

One example would be this function:

```
...
class String : public Object
{
     ...
    /*! 
    * \brief Trim the string from the left while the characters matches any characters in the given string
    * \param In_pChar - (optional) The array of characters to be trimmed
    * \return The trimmed string object
    */
    String& trim_left(const char * In_pChar=" \t");
    ...
};
...
```

Doxygen just completely omits the parameter and even warns about it:

```
warning: argument 'In_pChar' of command @param is not found in the argument list of String::trim_left()
```

The resulting HTML isn't really what I expected it to be:
[image: Screenshot of Doxygen HTML output]

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: There have been [many versions of Doxygen](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/changelog.html). Which one are you asking about?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Doxygen 1.8.13. I updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is almost certainly in one of your `...`s or you have a bugged version of doxygen.

The following code works fine for me:

```
class String : public Object                                                                            
{                                                                                     
public:                                                                                                 

/*!                                                                                                     
 * \brief Trim the string from the left while the characters matches any characters in the given string 
 * \param In_pChar - (optional) The array of characters to be trimmed                                   
 * \return The trimmed string object                                                                    
 */                                                                                                     
    String& trim_left(const char * In_pChar=" \t");                                                     

};
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I will try to narrow it down. Thank you.

Comment: The provided example works just fine. I haven't found the real issue yet.

Comment: That's why I said the problem could be in your `...`s and why it's important to post a [mcve] so the scope of the problem can be limited :)